# jQuery UI draggable randomly stops working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got many divs on the page (close to 20) which are both jQuery-UI resizable and draggable.  There are also some css-based changes that are triggered on mouseover and mouseout for each `div`. In the middle of playing around with these divs, sometimes, one of them just "gets stuck", i.e. just can't be dragged around any more. Using the Firebug and the console, I've seen that it does have both classes: `ui-draggable` and `ui-resizable` but it's still just "stuck". Is this something that normally happens with too many divs on the page? Just jQuery-UI get stuck like this? Most of the time everything works as expected, sometimes any of the `div`s suddenly  can't be moved.

My code to make things draggable was simple. For each div, I had a plugin that worked on itself, and part of its code was :

```
          $this.draggable({
            cursor: 'move'
            });
```

Comment: Could you post a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) showing the problem?

Comment: There's too much code, it's too involved, it's an entire application.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently encountered this problem and... I have no idea what the cause is. As far as I can tell it was probably caused by something happening around mouse handlers- possibly accidentally rebinding something that `draggable` was using, but I couldn't see any sign of it. Either way, draggable was failing silently and reverting the changes I was working on when it occurred did not help - the code which had worked at the start of the day was now also failing.

That is an indicator to me that something was weird with the way my browser and development server were interacting because that code worked earlier and now it had stopped. My solution was to stop the server, close the browser, run a `git clean -fdx` - *careful with that one*, other source control systems exist - on my project and then restart the server and client. Hey presto my old stuff worked - and the new code did too, once I popped it out of my git stash.